# Browsers don't show thumbnail preview on file upload menu

Tags: xubuntu, nautilus, firefox, google-chrome

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 and I have a problem with thumbnails not appearing on the file upload menu when I try to upload some images to a website. I checked with both Chrome and Firefox and some of the thumbnails are shown and others are not.

[image]

[image]

It looks like it doesn't depend on image size. I tried clearing the thumbnail cache, and also in nautilus I checked to show the thumbnails of 100mb large files. When I browse with thunar I can see the thumbnail previews of all the images, and also with any other program that I tried.

So the only problem is with thumbnails in the browsers' file upload menus.

Comment: Are you using nautilus or thunar

Comment: Well that one i don't know, there are both installed, nautilus and thunar, i know that i use thunar by default, but i don't know which one is activated when i open file upload menu in browser, it looks like thunar. The screenshoot is from firefox file upload menu.